# "But that is beacuse of many things" in german

Tags: english-to-german

I was wondering how you would say something like: "But that is because of many things" in german?

eg.: "In the last couple of months i have felt some stress. But that is because of many things."

Comment: The English as well as the German correspondence *Aber das hat viele Gründe/Ursachen* are completely straightforward. Why do you assume something is special?

Comment: @guidot Yes this is straightforward, indeed. I.e. when you know it has to be constructed in another way than in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually straight forward:

> (Aber) das hat viele Gründe/Ursachen

Nothig unusual about it.